# Is there such a thing as a "noncommutative field"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory

A field $F$ is a set that is essentially a commutative group in two ways:

> 1. $(F,+)$ is a commutative group with an identity element we call $0$.
> 2. $(F\setminus\{0\},\times)$ is a commutative group with an identity element we call $1$.
> 3. These two operations work together under some kind of distributive property: $a\times (b + c) = (a\times b) + (a\times c)$

This got me thinking, what if a set $G$ had these same three properties but we dropped the conditions of commutativity for one (or both) of the binary operations. Is this something that is interesting to algebraists? Does such a set not even exist? Do these kinds of object already some name that I am unaware of?

Any insight on this matter would be welcomed.

Comment: Cf. [division ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring), e.g., [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), though [any finite division ring is a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem)

Comment: For non-commutative *addition*, you might think about the real numbers under subtraction and multiplication.  You may lose some other field properties such as associativity since $(a-b)-c \not = a-(b-c)$ when $c \not=0$ and even perhaps an additive identity  since $0 -c \not = c$  when $c \not=0$ though you keep many others.

Comment: These are more generally called division algebras.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*(EDIT: this only addresses the noncommutative multiplication part of the question.)*

---

Sure, these are called **division rings** (or **skew fields**). There is a ton known about them, but here are a couple fun facts:

- Every *finite* division ring is in fact a field; this is [Wedderburn's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem).
- Every *semisimple* ring is "built out of" division rings, in the sense that it is a product of finitely many rings of the form $M_n(D)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $D$ a division ring; this is the [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%E2%80%93Artin_theorem).
- If $D$ is a division ring, then the center of $D$ is a field $d$, and $D$ is naturally an algebra over $d$. In case $D$ is finite dimensional over its center, we get that $D$ is a *central simple algebra* over $d$. Conversely, any finite-dimensional central simple algebra $A$ over a field $k$ is "very similar to" (= *Morita-equivalent* to) a unique-up-to-isomorphism division algebra $D$ with center $k$ and $dim_k(D)<\infty$. This is part of the (classical) theory of **Brauer groups**.

---

Meanwhile, I don't know much about noncommutative *addition*, but see the notion of [**near-rings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring). (Note, though, that distributivity gets messier if addition isn't commutative.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142721/discussion-on-answer-by-noah-schweber-is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-noncommutative); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that you are looking for the concept of a near-ring, i.e. a set together with two binary operations, none of which is necessarily commutative, but still satisfy a distributive property. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring

Near-rings arise by considering a (not necessarily abelian) group $G$ and the set $N$ of all functions $f\colon G\to G$. Then addition can be defined on $N$ in the usual way, which will be commutative iff $G$ is. Multiplication is also defined in the usual way, i.e. as a composition of functions.

Comment: Thank you! This was an interesting read, and something I had never heard of before. I will point out, however, that this example only forms a semiring over multiplication. Which indicates to me that that's the best we're going to achieve.